# How to sort dictionaries of objects by attribute value?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, attributes

I would like to iterate over a dictionary of objects in an attribute sorted way

```
import operator

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.age = age


studi1 = Student('john', 'A', 15)
studi2 = Student('dave', 'B', 10)
studi3 = Student('jane', 'B', 12)

student_Dict = {}
student_Dict[studi1.name] = studi1
student_Dict[studi2.name] = studi2
student_Dict[studi3.name] = studi3

for key in (sorted(student_Dict, key=operator.attrgetter('age'))):
    print(key)
```

This gives me the error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'age'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for student in (sorted(student_Dict.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('age'))):
    print(student.name)
```

Comment: This iterates over the values, sorted by the attribute. This may or may not be what you want; it isn't quite clear in the OP.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is definitely right that there's some ambiguity in the OP.  I believe that this method should be faster than mine, although I do think sorting over the keys is slightly more clear.

Comment: python 2.7 NameError: global name 'operator' is not defined

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> for key in sorted(student_Dict, key = lambda name: student_Dict[name].age):
...     print key
... 
dave
jane
john
```

Comment: This iterates over the keys, according to the corresponding value's attribute. This may or may not be what you want; it isn't quite clear in the OP.

Comment: @Karl: I think this is what the OP's looking for based on what they wrote.

Comment: great idiom here, so many applications

Answer (score 1):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
            self.name = name
            self.grade = grade
            self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
            return repr((self.name, self.grade, self.age))


student_objects = [
    Student('john', 'A', 15),
    Student('jane', 'B', 12),
    Student('dave', 'B', 10),
]
print student_objects
student_objects.sort(key=attrgetter('age'))
print student_objects
```

source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

How is showed in the documentation of [sorted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) method

```
sorted(student_Dict.keys(), key=lambda student: student.age)
```

Comment: You've missed the point. Iterating over a dict iterates over its keys. We are trying to sort the keys according to an attribute of the corresponding value.